# While running Docker container with external Spark I am getting this error

Tags: docker, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

My Spark is running on cluster mode. I assembly spark-cassandra-connector jar to my application jar then submitting the job from Docker. Still facing this issue.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2282)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2206)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2064)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How do you run your container?

Comment: Hi Maraf ,this is my dockerfile ,
FROM java:8-jre
COPY ./ms-analytics-ivu.1.0.1.jar /deploy/
ADD plugins/* /deploy/plugins/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/plugin/
CMD chmod +x ./deploy/ms-analytics-ivu.1.0.1.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/deploy/ms-analytics-ivu.1.0.1.jar","analytics","--spring$
EXPOSE 8087,here plugins contains some zip file ,while start the container zip file should extracted and run .Plugins contains spark which is connected to external pc .(10.**.**.***)

Comment: Please, edit your question and add add this information there. It's difficult to read your code since it is not formatted

Comment: Voting to close for lacking an [mcve] - moreover, the question appears to be abandoned.